# How to get listitem using jQueryUI

Tags: jquery, list, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use jQuery to get the values of the ListItems in an unordered list. The code below is close to working, but it always returns the value of the first ListItem, even if the second one is checked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li").click(function() {
        $("input:checked").each(function() {
            alert($("label").attr('InnerText'));
        });
    });
});
```

```js
<div> 
    <ul class="AspNet-CheckBoxList-RepeatDirection-Vertical">
        <li class="AspNet-CheckBoxList-Item">
            <input id="CheckBoxList1_0" type="checkbox" name="CheckBoxList1$0"  value="first1" />
            <label for="CheckBoxList1_0">First $30.00</label>
        </li>
        <li class="AspNet-CheckBoxList-Item">
            <input id="CheckBoxList1_1" type="checkbox" name="CheckBoxList1$1" value="second2" />
            <label for="CheckBoxList1_1">Second $25.00</label>
        </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your alert is referencing an attribute that doesn't exist. You should be seeing "undefined" in your alert.

Comment: try `.text()` instead of `attr('innerText')`

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zPK36/2/)**

- Use `.text()` instead of `.attr('innerText')` - `innerText` is a property of javascript object, won't work using `.attr()`.
- Use `$(this).next('label')` to get the associated label to the checkbox. In `.each()` - `$(this)` refers to the `checkbox` and **NOT** `li` clicked.

---

```
$("input:checked").each(function() {
      alert($(this).next('label').text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, `$("label")` maches all labels on the page (same with `$("input:checked")`)

You might want to try the following, to limit the selectors to only the children of the currently matched `li`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li").click(function() {
        $("input:checked", $(this)).each($.proxy(function() {
            alert($("label", $(this)).attr('InnerText'));
        }, this));
    });
});
```

Also, I don't see an `InnerText` attribute. Are you sure that wasn't supposed to be just `.text()`?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li").click(function() {
        if ($(this).find("input:checked")) {
            alert($(this).find("label").text());
        }
    });
});
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, just change the code as follows

```
$("li").click(function() {
    $("input:checked").siblings('label').each(function() {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

The `siblings()` method get the brothers for `input:checked`, in this case, you label

The example working is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nAkfa/)